# Compare multiple array of objects and convert it in to single objects by removing duplicates

Tags: javascript

```js
const data = [
  [{
      employee_number: 3,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 90,
    },
    {
      employee_number: 4,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 90,
    },
    {
      employee_number: 5,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 90,
    }
  ],
  [{
      employee_number: 3,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 45,
    },
    {
      employee_number: 4,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 50,
    },
    {
      employee_number: 5,
      sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182,
      sell_inc_tax_price: 60,
    }
  ]
]
```

I have multiple array of objects where i need to compare them and add there values(sell_inc_tax_price) and remove duplicates then convert it in to single array of objects

below is how i need the json object :

```js
const data = [{
    employee_number: 3,
    sell_ex_tax_price: 245.4546,
    sell_inc_tax_price: 175,
  },
  {
    employee_number: 4,
    sell_ex_tax_price: 245.4546,
    sell_inc_tax_price: 195,
  },
  {
    employee_number: 5,
    sell_ex_tax_price: 245.4546,
    sell_inc_tax_price: 220,
  }

]
```

In the above array the sell_ex_tax_price and sell_inc_tax_price are added only which has same employee_number  and converted them in to single array
how can I achieve this as they can be multiple arrays not just two or three over all i need to add and convert them in to single array.

Comment: Explain where the numbers in “how i need” are coming from; they aren't the sum of the numbers in your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply group the flat data by their `employee_number`.

```js
const
    data = [[{ employee_number: 3, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 90 }, { employee_number: 4, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 90 }, { employee_number: 5, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 90 }], [{ employee_number: 3, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 45 }, { employee_number: 4, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 50 }, { employee_number: 5, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 60 }],[{ employee_number: 3, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 40 }, { employee_number: 4, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 55 }, { employee_number: 5, sell_ex_tax_price: 81.8182, sell_inc_tax_price: 70 }]],
    result = Object.values(data
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
        .reduce((r, { employee_number, ...o }) => {
            r[employee_number] = r[employee_number] || { employee_number };
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) =>
                r[employee_number][k] = (r[employee_number][k] || 0) + v
            );
            return r;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for solution its working just one question can i use the concat or other then flat as it is giving lib error?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new array with objects an go through this array at every emlopyee. If there is already an object in this array with the employee's number, add sell_ex_tax_price and sell_inc_tax_price. If not, create a new one.

This could look like this (I didn't test it, so try it out):

```
dataSummarized = []
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<data[i].length; j++) {
        let dataExisting = false;
        for (k=0; i<dataSummarized.length; k++) {
            if(dataSummarized[k].employee_number==data[i][j].employee_number){
                dataSummarized[k].sell_ex_tax_price += data[i][j].sell_ex_tax_price;
                dataSummarized[k].sell_inc_tax_price += data[i][j].sell_inc_tax_price;
                dataExisting = true;
            }
        }
        if(!dataExisting){
            dataSummarized.push(data[i][j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: "its not working" doesn't really help to find a solution.

Comment: i tired with many solutions dint find any so i have asked you, becz of this code browser got stuck